# How to let phone calls from a specific number bypass 'Do Not Disturb'?

Tags: calls, ringtone, do-not-disturb

I often turn on 'Do Not Disturb' mode, especially at night. I would like a few specific phone numbers to be able to bypass the Do Not Disturb if they call me, so that I can be altered in case of emergency. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Never tried it, but doesn't "starring" a number whitelist it for DND? Or was there an additional setting involved? I just vaguely remember "starring" (marking a contact as favorite) was involved. Worth a try while waiting for answers. Let me know if it did the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set an exception rule to allow calls and texts from certain people (All/Contacts/Favorites).
Different manufacturers will have different set ups but you should be able to get to this setting by going

Settings > Sound & notification > Do Not Disturb > Exceptions

You may need to turn on Do Not Disturb to alter these settings.